# Oracle Database Users in synced database

Tags: sql, database, oracle, nhibernate, sql-server-ce

Ok so I have a little problem...
In my project we have a Oracle SQL Server. In the database I have access to some of an other users tables:

```
Tables:
  |-bla
  |-bla
Users:
  |-otherUser (let's just call him that)
      |-Tables:
          |-aTable
```

In Oracle, to access the `aTable` table I use `SELECT * FROM otherUser.aTable`

Now, we also have a MS SQL CE database to which I sync the data from the OracleDB using the MS Sync f/w. And in the CE db - after sync - I get a table `otherUser.aTable`. This sounds good, so even though the CE doesn't have the User concept it just adds the same table.

BUT the problem is that when calling the same SQL query on CE as on Oracle I get a *The table name is not valid* error. Instead if I want to get the content of the table, the two ways that I have found to work is surrounding the `otherUser.aTable` with either [] or "".

However neither of them seem to work with Oracle. The [] seem to be an illegal name, and the "" seem to search for a table called just that (not an other user).

So why don't I just use the one way on Oracle and the other on CE?  well I also use NHibernate as a ORM and it kind of needs the same table name for both the databases...

Is there a third way to encapsulate the table name that works with users in Oracle and just works in CE? or do you have any other ways to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with MS SQL, but it seems like a problem that might be solved with synonyms on Oracle side. 
Try to create synonym "otherUser.aTable" for otherUser.aTable in Oracle.